# Problems understanding the framework around a JXLoginPane example

Tags: java, swing, swingx, jxloginpane

I've found a component called `JXLoginPane` from [SwingX](https://java.net/projects/swingx) available in WindowBuilder and that seems like it would be a good starting point for what I am trying to do, but I need more information about how to use it. So far, the only thing I've found to really help me out with it is [this 9-year-old blog post](http://ignite.digitalignition.net/articlesexamples/swingx-jxloginpanel/).

It does get me most of the way there, but there are several references to things like `is.IS_Statics`, `is.MD5Hash`, and `isquote.Main` that the author does not provide. I am guessing that these are classes he or she has created just for logins, but I've no idea how to create them for myself.

How can I flesh out what Ruxton has started on his blog? Or, for that matter, can someone recommend an even better alternative to `JXLoginPane`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All answers will depend on your requirements, but most important thing is you understand what `JXLoginPane` is and how it works. Then you will be able to understand [that  9 years old post](http://ignite.digitalignition.net/articlesexamples/swingx-jxloginpanel/):

- [JXLoginPane](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXLoginPane.html): creates a panel with controls to authenticate users in a login based application.
- [LoginService](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/auth/LoginService.html): abstract base class that has to do the log-in logic and determine if user authentication is valid or not. It keeps an internal list of `LoginListener`s object that are notified on [LoginEvents](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/auth/LoginEvent.html) during the whole login process: login started, canceled, succeeded and failed.
- [PasswordStore](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/auth/PasswordStore.html): abstract class intended to safely store passwords typed by users in some kind of cache, in order to help  `LoginService` to authenticate users. The actual mechanism used to store the passwords is left up to the implementation.
- [UserNameStore](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/auth/UserNameStore.html): same as `PasswordStore` but for user names.
- [LoginListener](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/auth/LoginListener.html): this interface provides a contract to "listen" the current login process and act in consequence. For example if a login attempt fails for the same user 5 times you could block that user assuming someone is trying to hack that account, or if login process succeeded then you could create a new session entry in your database if you are interested in keep a log table with users sessions.

---

Now taking a quick look to that post, I think it's a database service based implementation combined with [Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) based users names cache for `UserNameStore`:

- Class `is.ISLoginService` is the `LoginService` abstract base class implementation.
- Class `is.ISUserNameStore` is the `UserNameStore` abstract class implementation.
- There's no implementation for `PasswordStore` abstract class.
- Class `is.ISLoginListener` is a `LoginListener` interface implementation.

Finally, regarding `is.IS_Statics`, `is.MD5Hash`, and `isquote.Main` seem to be utility classes of that specific project and have nothing to do with the essentials of `JXLoginPane`. You will probably have your own classes that help you with login process.

---

#### Simple example

Please consider this simple example that illustrates the concepts above described. You will see is not that difficult to make it work.

***Note:*** there's no user name nor password store implementations.
***Note 2:*** see [LoginAdapter](http://javadoc.geotoolkit.org/external/swingx/org/jdesktop/swingx/auth/LoginAdapter.html)

```
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXLoginPane;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.auth.LoginAdapter;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.auth.LoginEvent;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.auth.LoginListener;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.auth.LoginService;

public class Demo {

    private JFrame frame;
    private String userName;
    private int failedAttemptsCount = 0;

    private void showLoginDialog() {

        frame = new JFrame("Welcome!");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        final JXLoginPane loginPane = new JXLoginPane();

        LoginListener loginListener = new LoginAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void loginFailed(LoginEvent source) {
                failedAttemptsCount++;
                String message;
                switch(failedAttemptsCount) {
                    case 1: message = "Come on buddy! What happened?"; break;
                    case 2: message = "Did you just fail again?"; break;
                    case 3: message = "This is embarrassing..."; break;
                        default: message = "You should probably go home and get some sleep...";
                }
                loginPane.setErrorMessage(message);
            }

            @Override
            public void loginSucceeded(LoginEvent source) {
                Demo.this.userName = loginPane.getUserName();
                Demo.this.createAndShowGui();
            }
        };

        LoginService loginService = new LoginService() {
            @Override
            public boolean authenticate(String name, char[] password, String server) throws Exception {
                return name.equals("Sturm") 
                    && String.valueOf(password).equals("StackOverflow") ;
            }
        };

        loginService.addLoginListener(loginListener);
        loginPane.setLoginService(loginService);

        JXLoginPane.JXLoginDialog dialog = new JXLoginPane.JXLoginDialog(frame, loginPane);
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setVisible(true);

        // if loginPane was cancelled or closed then its status is CANCELLED
        // and still need to dispose main JFrame to exiting application
        if(loginPane.getStatus() == JXLoginPane.Status.CANCELLED) {
            frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
        }
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        String welcomeMessage = String.format("Welcome %s ! You have successfuly loged in.", userName);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel(welcomeMessage));

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Demo().showLoginDialog();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it does seem that the blog author was using some sort of other utility which uses "is" as its identifier for the classes it makes. `is.IS_Statics`, for example, probably is just a collection of `static` helper methods. And I'm guessing the `is.MD5Hash` class has stuff for encrypting/salting passwords and such. That, I'd love to learn more about. But I shall look more into those abstract classes and interfaces you mentioned, hoping to grok the whole thing better. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Once you understand this API correctly, you'll thank SwingLabs team.If you are interested to learn about encryption/salting then this is a great article to start with: [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) @Sturm

Answer (score 1):

Since you're just starting, I personally wouldn't use JXLoginPane.  Coding your own Login Panel isn't very hard, and I think I great place to learn about coding gui's and using swing.

I'll have to assume you know the basics about using swing.  If not, you'll really have to start right from scratch and go through the tutorials of how to create and use the basic swing components.  I'd also recommend netbeans as your IDE, the GUI builder is pretty decent to start.

As for a login panel, at it's very basics, all you need are two JTextFields and a JButton.  Everything else is basically just extra.

One JTextField will allow the user to enter their username, the other will take their password.  You will put an action listener on the JButton that when pressed will look up somewhere to see if that username exists, and if it does, does the password match, then take the appropriate action -- ie, unlock the rest of the program to use, tell the user the password is wrong, etc, etc.

Perhaps this is a good simple example?
http://www.novell.com/documentation/developer/samplecode/bns_ldap_sample/LoginSample/Login.java.html

There are two methods in here you will absolutely have to code yourself.  doSearch() and doLogin(String fullName).  If you're just learning, you could do something simple, like just hard coding in some usernames and passwords, or reading from a text file to see if there is a match instead of setting up and connecting to a database.  doLogin can just be as simple as something like having all your JComponents disabled, then enabling them on a successful login.

Comment: Actually, I've been dealing with Swing for the past few months, so I'm no longer a stranger to it, although I'm still an amateur. And by the way, WindowBuilder for Eclipse is an excellent alternative to NetBeans, IMHO.

I've no doubt that I could code my own login dialog that is very simple, but that means unsecured passwords. And while security isn't of the highest concern in my program, I would still like to learn about better ways of doing it: encrypting, salting, whatever.